# Rotate a matrix in Prolog

Tags: list, matrix, prolog

How can I rotate a 4 x 4 matrix about its center point in Prolog ? I can simply rearrange the elements in case of 4 x 4 matrix but how to do this for a general case like N x N ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is *not quite* matrix transposition... but **almost!**

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

matrix_rotated(Xss, Zss) :-
   transpose(Xss, Yss),
   maplist(reverse, Yss, Zss).
```

Sample query:

```
?- matrix_rotated([[a1,a2,a3,a4],
                   [b1,b2,b3,b4],
                   [c1,c2,c3,c4]], Xss).
Xss = [[c1,b1,a1],
       [c2,b2,a2],
       [c3,b3,a3],
       [c4,b4,a4]].
```

Comment: At least add the rotation by 180 degrees, too: `reverse(M, R0), maplist(reverse, R0, R)`. Plus make the distinction between rotating 90 degrees clockwise and counterclockwise.

Comment: @Boris. (2) I get. Do you have a good name? (1) What do you mean? I wrote down (by hand) a single full rotation (4 steps) as a test case, and `matrix_rotated/2` matched that nicely. So why the second `reverse`? (Yes, I did not write any code before I wrote the testcases, hurray!)

Comment: @Boris. It sure deserves it! Runtime wasn't my primary concern: "*premature optimization is the root ...*"

Comment: @Boris. Fair enough. I did not mean to patronize you! Instead see my comment as honest advice to myself: after all, I **am** a premature optimization addict in recovery:)

Comment: I did not feel patronized. As I tried to point out, this is not about runtime, this is about the problem definition. I will be forced to write an answer myself, it seems :)

Comment: @Boris. I see, I think. Exploiting algebraic properties **is** a high-level contribution.

Answer (score 3):

Someone is [*wrong* on the internet](https://xkcd.com/386/), so duty calls.
We must obey [Cunningham's Law](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cunningham's_Law), after all.

This answer makes good use of [library(clpfd)](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd) as found in [SWI-Prolog](http://swi-prolog.org).

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

rotate_clockwise(Matrix, N, Rotated) :-
    N_mod_4 #= N mod 4,
    rotate_clockwise_(N_mod_4, Matrix, Rotated).

rotate_clockwise_(0, M, M).
rotate_clockwise_(1, M, R) :-
    transpose(M, R0),
    maplist(reverse, R0, R).
rotate_clockwise_(2, M, R) :-
    reverse(M, R0),
    maplist(reverse, R0, R).
rotate_clockwise_(3, M, R) :-
    transpose(M, R0),
    reverse(R0, R).
```

You can rotate a rectangular matrix by flipping it twice (try it out with a book or something).
Depending on the two axes along which you flip, you get one of the 3 non-trivial rotations: if we agree that "one rotation" is 90 degrees clockwise, then you can rotate 0, 1, 2, or 3 times. In the code above:

- flip along horizontal axis is `reverse`
- flip along vertical axis is `maplist(reverse)`
- flip along the top-left-lower-right axis is `transpose`

As to why not just define rotating once 90 degrees clockwise and then rotate multiple times: well, it is actually more code!
With the definition above, no matter what valid arguments we give to `rotate_clockwise/3`, it does the right rotation, doesn't do unnecessary flips, and keeps the caller code short.

```
?- rotate_clockwise([[a,b,c],[d,e,f]], -1, R). % once counter-clockwise
R = [[c, f], [b, e], [a, d]].

?- rotate_clockwise([[a,b,c],[d,e,f]], 2, R). % 180 degrees
R = [[f, e, d], [c, b, a]].

?- rotate_clockwise([[a,b,c],[d,e,f]], 168, R). % rotate once each hour, for a week
R = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f]].

?- rotate_clockwise([[a,b,c],[d,e,f]], N, R). % enumerate all possibilities
R = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f]],
N mod 4#=0 ;
R = [[d, a], [e, b], [f, c]],
N mod 4#=1 ;
R = [[f, e, d], [c, b, a]],
N mod 4#=2 ;
R = [[c, f], [b, e], [a, d]],
N mod 4#=3.

?- Matrix = [[a],[b]],
   rotate_clockwise(Matrix, -1, R),
   rotate_clockwise(Matrix, 3, R). % those two mean the same
Matrix = [[a], [b]],
R = [[a, b]].
```

Comment: @mat You know it, I know it: it's CLPFD that's cool, not this toy example :) It was a great decision to include `transpose/2` in the library, btw; once I had to pull `library(clpfd)` as a dependency, there is absolutely no reason not to use the arithmetic, too. Other highlight (for me personally) are `zcompare/3` and `chain/2`.

Comment: It's this insight and embracing it that's cool! Slowly and methodically, we will change how Prolog programs are written. The things that still appear unusual now shall become folklore in due time.

Comment: s(X): Now that's a nice and intuitive interface. Kudos from me:)

Comment: A small but: With stating "*doesn't do unnecessary flips*", you **are** referring to procedural code properties, not properties of the relation *itself*—even if the measurement unit you picked is abstract, and not runtime.

Comment: @repeat We are getting philosophical again :) "Code" is an interesting thing, and writing it even more so. It is, just like mathematical proofs, a social activity, in the sense that we use it to communicate to other people. At the same time, writing code is how we communicate our intentions to machines that are (still) procedural by their nature.

Answer (score 1):

as noted, [transpose](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=transpose/2)/2 isn't the right solution. I've coded something (maybe a bit too much general), that allows to specify the amount of rotation in term of number of cells to shift to right. Shift defaults to 1, but then I noted that to get 90° rotations, the shift is decreasing while passing to inner frames. Passing an anonymous variable to matrix_rotate/3 has the effect of using the current inner frame size. Then, it rotates 90° clockwise.

```
/** <module> matrix_rotate
 *
 *  answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594027/rotate-a-matrix-in-prolog
 *  --------
 *
 *  source file /home/carlo/prolog/matrix_rotate.pl
 *  created at mer feb 24 16:43:50 2016
 *
 *  @author carlo
 *  @version 0.9.9
 *  @copyright carlo
 *  @license LGPL v2.1
 */

:- module(matrix_rotate,
    [matrix_rotate/2
    ,matrix_rotate/3
    ,matrix_allocate/4
    ,matrix_row_col_element/4
    ,rowcol/3
    ]).

:- meta_predicate matrix_allocate(3, +,+,-).

matrix_allocate(Pred, NRows, NCols, Mat) :-
    bagof(Vs, Row^(
        between(1, NRows, Row),
        bagof(C, Col^(between(1, NCols, Col), call(Pred, Row, Col, C)), Vs)
    ), Mat).

empty(_R,_C,_).
rowcol(R, C, (R,C)).

matrix_rotate(Mat, Rot) :-
    matrix_rotate(Mat, 1, Rot).
matrix_rotate(Mat, Shift, Rot) :-
    matrix_is_square(Mat, Size),
    matrix_allocate(empty, Size, Size, Rot),
    frames_shift(Mat, Shift, 1, Rot),
    (   Size mod 2 =:= 1
    ->  Cen is Size // 2 + 1,
        matrix_row_col_element(Mat, Cen, Cen, E),
        matrix_row_col_element(Rot, Cen, Cen, E)
    ;   true
    ).

frames_shift(Mat, Shift, Frame, Rot) :-
    length(Mat, Size),
    Frame =< Size // 2,
    (   integer(Shift)
    ->  ActualShift = Shift
    ;   ActualShift is Size - (Frame - 1)*2 - 1
    ),
    frame(Mat, Frame, L),
    shift_right(L, ActualShift, S),
    frame(Rot, Frame, S),
    F is Frame+1,
    !, frames_shift(Mat, Shift, F, Rot).
frames_shift(_Mat, _Shift, _Frame, _Rot).

matrix_is_square(Mat, Size) :-
    length(Mat, Size),
    forall(member(Row, Mat), length(Row, Size)).

matrix_row_col_element(Mat, Row, Col, El) :-
    nth1(Row, Mat, Cells),
    nth1(Col, Cells, El).

shift_right(List, Shift, Shifted) :-
    length(Post, Shift),
    append(Pre, Post, List),
    append(Post, Pre, Shifted).

frame(Mat, N, Frame) :-
    length(Mat, S),
    T is N, B is S-N+1,
    L is N, R is S-N+1,
    matrix_range_elements(Mat, T,T, L,R-1, Top),
    matrix_range_elements(Mat, T,B-1, R,R, Right),
    matrix_range_elements(Mat, B,B, R,L+1, Bottom),
    matrix_range_elements(Mat, B,T+1, L,L, Left),
    append([Top, Right, Bottom, Left], Frame).

matrix_range_elements(Mat, RStart, RStop, CStart, CStop, Elems) :-
    bagof(E, matrix_element_between(Mat, RStart, RStop, CStart, CStop, E), Elems).

matrix_element_between(Mat, RStart, RStop, CStart, CStop, Elem) :-
    signed_between(RStart, RStop, R),
    signed_between(CStart, CStop, C),
    matrix_row_col_element(Mat, R, C, Elem).

signed_between(Start, Stop, I) :-
    A is Start, B is Stop,
    ( B < A -> between(B, A, N), I is A+B-N ; between(A, B, I) ).
```

This snippets highlights some general pattern useful while processing matrices as list of lists. And some of the difficulties, too...

Example usage:

```
?- matrix_allocate(rowcol,4,4,M),matrix_rotate(M,_,R),maplist(writeln,R).
[(4,1),(3,1),(2,1),(1,1)]
[(4,2),(3,2),(2,2),(1,2)]
[(4,3),(3,3),(2,3),(1,3)]
[(4,4),(3,4),(2,4),(1,4)]
M = [[(1, 1),  (1, 2),  (1, 3),  (1, 4)], [(2, 1),  (2, 2),  (2, 3),  (2, 4)], [(3, 1),  (3, 2),  (3, 3),  (3, 4)], [(4, 1),  (4, 2),  (4, 3),  (4, 4)]],
R = [[(4, 1),  (3, 1),  (2, 1),  (1, 1)], [(4, 2),  (3, 2),  (2, 2),  (1, 2)], [(4, 3),  (3, 3),  (2, 3),  (1, 3)], [(4, 4),  (3, 4),  (2, 4),  (1, 4)]].

?- matrix_allocate(rowcol,3,3,M),matrix_rotate(M,_,R),maplist(writeln,R).
[(3,1),(2,1),(1,1)]
[(3,2),(2,2),(1,2)]
[(3,3),(2,3),(1,3)]
M = [[(1, 1),  (1, 2),  (1, 3)], [(2, 1),  (2, 2),  (2, 3)], [(3, 1),  (3, 2),  (3, 3)]],
R = [[(3, 1),  (2, 1),  (1, 1)], [(3, 2),  (2, 2),  (1, 2)], [(3, 3),  (2, 3),  (1, 3)]].
```

Comment: Transpose is not the same as rotate, is it?

Comment: @Boris:  yes, my fault... I'm crafting something reusable... I'll remove the above code when done

Comment: Why do you require that `matrix_is_square/2` holds?

Comment: @repeat: lazyness... it took too long to write the squared version... squareness is required by frame/3